# How can I access the resources saved in the cache by a ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to build a webpage that uses ServiceWorker. I followed [this example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/) (for Chrome 45+), which seems to cache some data.
I tried to access the cached data but without success.

Is it possible to find the cached data via the Chrome console (similarly to Local Storage)?
Is there any simple JS code I can run from the console to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can see what's in the cache. Looking at the source code from the sample repository you're using, I see that it is storing the cached urls in a cache called `CURRENT_CACHES['post-message']`. If you're in the service worker (go to `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, find the relevant service worker, and inspect it), this snippet of code will log the urls currently stored in that cache:

```
caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['post-message']).then(function(cache) {
  cache.keys().then(function(requests) {
    var urls = requests.map(function(request) {
      return request.url;
    });
    console.log(urls.sort());
  });
});
```

Basically you're just opening the cache, calling `keys()` on it, and logging the url for each key (or cache record) that is returned.

Comment: The Cache Storage API is also exposed as `window.caches` in recent versions of Chrome, so you can execute that code from the DevTools in a controlled page, without going to the service worker DevTools. It's also exposed visually in the DevTools' Resources tab: https://twitter.com/jeffposnick/status/546494702842028032

Comment: How can I access the resources themselves (and not only to their URLls)?

Comment: You can use `caches.match` to get the response objects. For example, `caches.match("https://www.google.com/").then(function(response){console.log(response);});`. You can use a url or a request object with `caches.match`. For example you could get the keys and then use one of the keys with `caches.match`.

Comment: @BrendanRitchie I failed to retrieve a response via this code (the comment code) or via its modifications. I also failed to see the content via the Chrome console as pointed by Jeff Posnick. I see only the response status (OK) but not the resources themselves.

Comment: I just tested it myself on the sample site and the code I provided worked there after I cached a couple of urls. It sounds like your implementation is not actually caching things. Have you implement everything in the actual service worker script itself (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/post-message/service-worker.js)?

Answer (score 0):

Elevating this out of a comment:

The Cache Storage API is also exposed as window.caches in recent versions of Chrome, so you can execute that code from the DevTools in a controlled page, without going to the service worker DevTools. It's also exposed visually in the DevTools' Resources tab: twitter.com/jeffposnick/status/546494702842028032 – Jeff Posnick Sep 2 '15 at 17:51

With thanks to Jeff P.